# Unable to delete locked file

Tags: macos, terminal, file

I have a locked file on my machine that I'm unable to delete. I've tried everything (that I know of) and don't have a clue why it won't delete.

Here's what I tried:

1. Everything [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26670/unable-to-delete-a-file)
2. sudo rm file.txt
3. chflags -R nouchg file.txt
4. unlocked the file in "get info"

None of which worked.

Here is the typical result I get (admin is "me"):

```
$ sudo chflags -R nouchg file.txt
$ sudo rm file.txt
override rw-r--r--  me/staff sappnd,schg for file.txt? y
rm: file.txt: Operation not permitted
```

**WTF** is going on here???

---

UPDATE: tried this and still no joy:

```
$ sudo chflags noschg file.txt
$ sudo rm file.txt
override rw-r--r--  me/staff sappnd for file.txt? y
rm: file.txt: Operation not permitted
```

UPDATE2: turns out there was another flag also `sappnd`:

```
$ sudo chflags sappnd file.txt
$ sudo rm file.txt
```

The flags on the file were the cause, so after removing them the file could be deleted. I'm not sure if there's a way to remove all the flags at once, but would have been easier.

Comment: Do you know what the file is? (As in, did you make it, or did something in the system put it there?)

Comment: @user24601 It's empty - created using `touch file.txt`

Comment: You asked "...remove all the flags at once..." and from OS X Man Pages for [CHFLAGS(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/chflags.1.html) it shows the "SYNOPSIS" as, `chflags [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] flags file ...` and further down the page is says "The flags are specified as an octal number or a comma separated list of keywords.".  So you could have used `ls -lO` to see what flags were set and if it was set as e.g., `uchg,sappnd,schg` then used the command as `sudo chflags nouchg,nosappnd,noschg file.txt` to unset all at one time.

Comment: @user3439894 That comment of yours was just the quick fix 'answer' I needed just now. Thx. But: doesn't that belong into the larger box below?